# How can I make an Android app compatible with BrailleBack?

Tags: android, accessibility, braille

I'm looking to make the Android app I work on more accessible, and was wondering if we need to do anything special to make it compatible with services like BrailleBack so it can be used with braille readers like this one:
https://uk.optelec.com/products/abc-640-en-uk-alva-bc640.html

We've already used tools like the accessibility scanner to help us identify changes that can make the app compatible with screen readers. Can anyone recommend any tutorials, etc. that can help us build compatibility with braille readers and services like BrailleBack? Or is it just very similar approach to services like TalkBack, technically speaking?

I've tried looking through Google's developer documentation and accessibility support, but no luck.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/additional-resources
https://support.google.com/accessibility/android#topic=6007234

It would be great to have an app that is better prepared for visually impaired users. Many thanks :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have actually done everything correctly.

Braille Screens and Readers take the input from a screen reader and turn it into Braille.

BrailleBack interacts with Google TalkBack to turn the output from TalkBack into a format that a Braille Screen / Keyboard can understand.

If you can use the App with TalkBack with no accessibility issues then it should work with BrailleBack.

I am aware that some Apps have issues with scrolling past the first screen using a Braille display.

As far as I am aware this is a bug in BrailleBack but that may be the one area you need to research more as i have never experienced it personally and it is only second hand information colleagues have told me about in the past.

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain a bit more what you mean by "scrolling past the first screen"?

Comment: When you use a Braille Display it still scrolls the page to identify content and reveal lazy loaded content. Occasionally this can apparently malfunction, I have never seen it myself but it is just what someone has mentioned to me in passing as one of the frustrations of BrailleBack.